# How much the Earth atmosphere oscillates due to Moon tidal force and does this produces winds?

Tags: atmospheric-science, earth, estimation, moon, tidal-effect

As there is the tidal force of the Moon exerted on the Ocean water I supose there must be some force acting to the Earth's atmosphere. So when the atmosphere starts falling down as the Moon is travelling away does this effect causes winds oriented away from the point that is closest to the Moon?

Comment: Could start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_tide

Comment: @BowlOfRed So winds are dominantly caused by solar heating?

Comment: That would be my assumption, but I have not studied that area in any depth.  This would seem to be an excellent question for https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The atmosphere does not oscillate by any known measurement due to the moon's title forces now other heavenly bodies do call slight deviations or isolations in atmospheric gases you have to remember that the atmosphere is extremely thin. If you look at a schoolroom globe the atmosphere is approximately the size of the lacquer on that globe.

Comment: Is being thin a reason not to oscillate?